# Infinite Update Loop in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having an issue with the following updated error in my navigation tabs component:

*You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.*

[image]

Looking through previous questions on here, most seem to be related to computed properties, or directly modifying props passed into a component forcing them to continuously re-render. However in this component I don't think I am trying to do either.

```
Vue.component('navigation-tabs', {
    props: {
        tabs: Array,
        title: String,
        type: String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            navigationTabs: Vue.util.extend([], this.tabs),
            selectedTab: {},
            tabCounter: 0,
            tabType: this.type ? this.type : 'tabs'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        navItemClasses(selectedTab) {
            if (selectedTab.selected) {
                if (this.type) {
                    return 'bg-gradient-dark text-white';
                }
            } else if (selectedTab.disabled === true) {
                return 'text-danger';
            }
        },
        selectTab(selectedTab) {
            if (selectedTab.disabled !== true) {
                this.navigationTabs.forEach(tab => {
                    tab.selected = false;
                });
                selectedTab.selected = true;
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        activeComponent() {
            return this.navigationTabs.filter(x => x.selected === true)[0]
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul class="text-md nav" :class="tabType === 'tabs' ? 'nav-tabs' : 'nav-pills'">
                    <li v-for="(tab, index) in navigationTabs" class="nav-item card-img-holder" v-if="tab.hideForSite !== $parent.site">
                         <img src="/shared/resources/images/circle.svg" class="card-img-absolute">
                         <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" :class="navItemClasses(tab)" @click="selectTab(tab)">
                         {{ tabCounter++ + ': ' + tab.name }}
                         </a>
                    </li>   
                    <h3 v-if="title" class="nav-link font-weight-bold ml-auto pb-0">{{ title }}</h3>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div v-if="tabType !== 'tabs'" class="border-top my-3"></div>
            <div class="my-4 mx-5">
                <component :is="activeComponent.component"></component>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
});
```

I only even spotted this when trying to display / log the values of *tabCounter* on the screen, allowing me to display an accurate number beside each shown tab. If I remove the counter I don't get the error at all, which seems unusual to me as I am not really doing much with it. It is making me worry that something is wrong in the background, as even when I only have 6 tabs to display, the counter is cycling upto a value of over 700.

[image]

I have included a copy of the parent app below for reference, any help would be really appreciated.

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        site: '1',
        myTabs: [
            {
                name: 'Example 1',
                selected: true,
                component: 'example-one'
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 2',
                component: 'example-two'
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 3',
                component: 'example-three'
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 4',
                component: 'example-four'
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 5',
                component: 'example-five',
                hideForSite: 'DC4'
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 6',
                component: 'example-six'
            },
            {
                name: 'Example 7',
                disabled: true
            },
        ]
    },
    created() {
        this.site = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + 'Siteinstance' + '=([^;]*)(;|$)')[2].toUpperCase();
    }
});
```

Edit:
Originally I wasn't doing the increment in the template, and was calling a function, but don't get why it is called 600+ times:

```
<a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" :class="navItemClasses(tab)" @click="selectTab(tab)">
    {{ retrievePosition() + ': ' + tab.name }}
</a>

    retrievePosition(){
        return this.tabCounter++;
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabCounter++` updates `tabCounter` every time the component is rendered, this causes a re-render and results in infinite loop.

In case there's a need for a counter, there's already index value:

```
{{ (index + 1) + ': ' + tab.name }}
```

Try to avoid side effects during rendering (inside component template and `render` function) because this is a bad practice that can result in infinite loop. If a side effect should be constantly performed, watchers and `beforeUpdate` and `updated` lifecycle hooks are suitable places.

Comment: I did try this already, however some of the tabs are hidden depending on the site that is selected, so I am no just able to add 1 to the index as it will skip from 4 -> 6 for example. Have added an edit for something I change, I still don't get why it renders hundreds of time, is this something I am doing?

Comment: You can `filter` tabs before outputting them, this way `index` will be correct value. Move `tab.hideForSite !== $parent.site` check to computed property, the same way you did for `activeComponent`. Yes, it's something you're doing,  `tabCounter++` makes it work like: `var tabCounter = 0; function render() { var oldTabCounter = tabCounter; console.log(tabCounter++); if (oldTabCounter !== tabCounter) render(); } render();`. Try to run it and you'll get infinite loop that will possibly freeze your browser.

Comment: Yea that makes more sense thank you. So basically whenever I incremented the counter, it was causing the component to re-render which then caused the counter to be incremented again, causing a loop of these events to happen? Just want to make sure that is correct in my head.